# Setting auto_increment_increment = 1 effect on existing tables

Tags: mysql, database, auto-increment

I created a new MySql table and saw that the auto-increment field starts with a value of 3 and increments by 2. I do a `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'auto_inc%';` and get this-

```
auto_increment_increment 2
auto_increment_offset 2
```

I did some research and found that I need to use-

```
SET @@auto_increment_increment=1;  and
SET @@auto_increment_offset=1;
```

But my question is, will setting both these values to 1 affect how rows are inserted on other tables with auto-increment fields? Will the new rows inserted on those tables start with an auto-increment id of 1 now? Or will this only affect new tables going forward?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The effect of `auto_increment_increment` and `auto_increment_offset` is not per-table, it applies to all tables you insert into.

If you use `SET` in your own session, the variable will be changed in your session only. The behavior in other sessions will not change. Also if you disconnect and reconnect, your session settings are reset to the global settings.

To make the change global, you need to use `SET GLOBAL`. But the change will be undone the next time MySQL Server restarts.

To make the change global *and* persistent, either edit the `my.cnf` file so the variable is set every time MySQL Server starts, or else in MySQL 8.0 they added a feature so you can now use `SET PERSIST` so you can change global variables and it will retain the setting after a restart.

You can read more about this:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/using-system-variables.html
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-variable.html

Comment: Points noted. Thanks.